# How to uninstall zsh

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh

I'm new to Mac. A friend installed all kinds of additional software including `zsh` which I would like to uninstall. So how can I uninstall `zsh`?

Comment: Why do you want to **uninstall** it? Some other packages might need it and it comes with the OS.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

If your friend changed the command that shells are opened with, you can change it back to the default login shell from Terminal's preferences:

[image]

If the default login shell was changed, you can change it back to `/bin/bash` by running `chsh -s /bin/bash`.

zsh is included with OS X (in `/bin/zsh`), but even if your friend installed a newer version of zsh, you don't necessarily need to uninstall or remove it.